# Ninject: Passing client's assembly as constructor argument and specifying desired implementation from the client using attributes

Tags: c#, binding, dependency-injection, ninject, constructor-injection

I'm new to Ninject and Dependency Injection in general so please excuse my noobness here.  =)

I have several implementations of an `IConfig` interface which scan an Assembly and its dependencies for types implementing an `IConfigOption` interface. Each `IConfig` implementation retrieves their values from different sources.

These implementations take the root Assembly from where to start scanning as a constructor argument, and I'm trying to come up with a binding that injects these values. So far I'm thinking of something in the lines of:

```
Bind<IConfig>().To<Config>().WithConstructorArgument("rootAssembly", target);
```

My problem is, I can't seem to find a way to get a reference to the `target` Assembly where the `Config` class would be injected. Without DI, I would use `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()`, but in this context this yields the Assembly where the binding resides, and not the target one as desired.

Also, I need a way of specifying the intended implementation **from the class/member that will receive the injection**, so that for example, client class A asks for a `Config` implementor that uses `RoleEnvironment` and client class B asks for a `Config` implementor that uses `ConfigurationManager`. Here's an example to clarify the intended usage:

```
public class Client
{
    [UseApplicationConfig]
    public IHelper WithAppConfig { get; set; }

    [UseRoleEnvironmentConfig]
    public IHelper WithRoleEnvironmentConfig { get; set; }
}

public class Helper : IHelper
{
    public Helper(IConfig config)
    {
    }
}
```

I get the feeling that either I'm looking at this from the wrong angle or I'm missing the obvious, but i'm not sure what I should be looking for. How would be the best way to do it?

Thank you very much.

EDIT: Added an example of the intended usage and rephrased some parts of the question for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get details about the request that's being made to the object, use the overload `WithConstructorArgument(string, Func<IContext, object>)`. You can use the supplied `IContext` to look for the assembly name (use the debugger to look around, it sounds like your layout might be quite complex so I can't offer specific code).

As an example of how to use this:

```
//get the full name of the requested object
Bind<IFoo>()
    .To<Foo>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("bar",
                             c => c.Request.FullName);
```

However, it sounds to me like you're looking at it from the wrong angle. If I read your question correctly, it sounds like you have a class that scans your assemblies and then decides what to inject instead of letting Ninject do it for you. I assume this is a leftover from when you weren't using DI?

I'd take a look at using contextual binding with the `WhenInjectedInto` method or custom attributes to inject the specific `IHelper` that you want into the constructor. See here: https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding

The linked page actually has an example of doing something similar that may work for you:

```
Bind<IWarrior>()
    .To<Samurai>()
    .When(request => request.Target.Type.Namespace.StartsWith("Samurais.Climbing"));
```

I'd probably still use `WhenInjectedInto` or attributes though so you don't have any "magic strings" in case you refactor your namespaces later.

Comment: That class just scans for implementors of `IConfigOption` and adds them to a collection, it does not inject anything. I thought about the solution you mention. The problem is that I need it to be context agnostic. Therefore, manually checking who requested the injection by name or type is not an option, and that's why I thought using attributes would be a better way if only I knew how to implement it.

(I'm probably still looking at this from the wrong angle though)

Anyway, thanks a lot for your response, I had almost given up hope on this question. :)

Comment: I did exactly that, and I think the assembly was exactly where you pointed. However, it was the assembly where the class to be injected resided, and not the one where it should be injected to. I think it had something to do with it losing the original context somehow (can't remember the details right now). I even tried the ContextPreservation plugin but could never find the target assembly anywhere, but I _think_ it only happened when doing `kernel.Get<T>()`, and not when using constructor injection. One of those methods actually worked. Pretty weird.